# How to Convert mysql to array result with number

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have php code like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM `rcpa_users` WHERE upline_users = '$selectuname'");
while($tjans = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){    

print_r($tjans);

}
```

But output show this

```
Array ( [userName] => mita ) 
Array ( [userName] => wendyang ) 
Array ( [userName] => viviekosasih )
```

Now, how to convert array like this result

```
Array
(
    [0] => mita
    [1] => wendyang
    [2] => viviekosasih
)
```

so I can call with echo $tjans[0], $tjans[1], $tjans[2]

Thank You..

Comment: for starters stop using `mysql_*` as it is deprecated and removed in PHP 7. start learning to use either `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: this is just a simple array assignment `$array[] = $tjans['userName']`

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` will be returning both in numeric key and field name as key. But as u request if all the rows are to be aligned then you had to push data into arrays inside the loop.

Comment: @Mr Zy. I have added more codes to the answer. Share me with your thought. Added the code for Multiple data and single row of data too.

Comment: @Naresh Kumar.P Okay, Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` - Fetch a result row as an associative array.This function will return a row as an associative array where the column names will be the keys storing corresponding value.

**Description:** Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. mysql_fetch_assoc() is equivalent to calling mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC for the optional second parameter. It only returns an associative array.

After that you need to do the `array_values()` so that it converts all the values to array with numeric keys.

`array_values` — Return all the values of an array

`array_values()` returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

> If your query returns multiple rows as output you can prefer this method:

```
$sqlxx = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM rcpa_users WHERE upline_users = '$selectuname'"); 
$final_tjans = array();
while($tjans = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlxx))
{
    $final_tjans[] = $tjans['userName'];
}
print_r($final_tjans);
```

> If you code returns only single row as output:

```
$sqlxx = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM rcpa_users WHERE upline_users = '$selectuname'"); 
$tjans = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlxx));
$final_tjans = array_values($tjans); 
print_r($final_tjans);
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```

> **Note:** Usage of `mysql` extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Output show this :(

Array ( [0] => mita ) Array ( [0] => wendyang ) Array ( [0] => viviekosasih )

Comment: With this php code 
$sqlxx = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM `rcpa_users` WHERE upline_users = '$selectuname'");
       while($tjans = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlxx)){
        
       print_r(array_values($tjans));
       }

Comment: Are you getting single row of data or multiple rows of data by executing that query

Comment: only single row

Comment: Remove the while loop and then perform the array values options

Comment: Try this which i send below

Comment: `$sqlxx = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM rcpa_users WHERE upline_users = '$selectuname'"); 
$tjans = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlxx))
$final_tjans = array_values($tjans); 
print_r($final_tjans);`

Comment: Ping me if you face error again. So that we shall look forward for some other techniques.

Comment: @Mr Zy. Have you obtained the output as required by you.

Comment: This code only get one result..

Array ( [0] => mita )

How to showing result like

Array
(
    [0] => mita
    [1] => wendyang
    [2] => viviekosasih
)

Comment: I asked you right whether you are getting single row or multiple lines of output. You mentioned only single row.

Comment: For single row you can perform the one which i suggested. For multiple rows i will provide with the code now.

Comment: Try this for multiple datas.

Comment: `$sqlxx = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM rcpa_users WHERE upline_users = '$selectuname'"); 
$final_tjans = array();
while($tjans = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlxx))
{
 $final_tjans[] = $tjans['userName'];
}
print_r($final_tjans);`

Comment: Awesome :D , Great Thank You

Comment: Fine. Its my pleasure helping you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple records then simple getting array with array_values will not work as it will only returns a single row .
To get all rows from this query you need to fetch through each row .
Like below

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $tjan = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)  ) {
        $tjan[] = $row['price'];
    }
    print_r($tjan);
}
```

Then add 'price' field in an array that must be blank before loop.
At last you will get an array as you want .
Cheers ,

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I have added ,I am some new in answering so It might need some correction now also . But thanks for pointing it .

Answer (score 0):

You need not run a loop at all. Store your result in an array:

```
$tjans = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$tjans = array_values($tjans);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use mysqli instead of mysql as it is depreciated and there is no need to use the loop of any kind as your Select query will fetch all the records matching your where condition. Following is the code snippet you may use.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT userName FROM `rcpa_users` WHERE upline_users = '$selectuname'");
$tjans = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
print_r(array_values($tjans));
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create an array and store the **userName** into it, and outside the while loop print the array to see the output.

```
$new_array = array();
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT userName FROM `rcpa_users` WHERE upline_users = '$selectuname'");
while($tjans = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
    $new_array[] = $tjans->userName;
}

print_r($new_array);
```

**What i change in your code??**

1. Remove all the `mysql_*` into `mysqli_*`.
2. Create an array for the further store of `userName` and store.
3. print the new array outside the loop.
4. And the final one is use the `$conn` variable. This is the connection string, you have to learn about this. [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

> **Note:** The [original MySQL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is now deprecated,
>   and will generate **E_DEPRECATED** errors when connecting to a
>   database. Instead, use the
>   [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or
>   [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions.